# Which of these structures are good for maintaining historical data?

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices

I am creating an application which is being used to send reminders. Here is the requirements.

1. We have set of Students.
2. Every student has a `Student Pass`, this need to be renewed in every month. `Student Pass` has Pass ID, monetary value, date of expiry, etc.
3. Before 7 days of `Student Pass` expiry, we have to send notifications to the system admin.
4. We have to monitor the `Student Pass History` of every student as well. Which means how many notifications were given to the admin, what is the date the pass got expired and so on.

Now we need to create tables for this. We thought of creating a table called `StudentPass` and maintaining the `student pass history` and `current student pass` in the same table. It is like below

[image]

However maintaining the `current student pass data` and `student pass history` seems to be
mixed up work because we have to send notification for the expiration of `current student pass`. So we decided to divide this into 2 tables. It is like below, the `current student pass data` will be maintained in `StudentPass` table and the history data will be maintained in `StudentPassHistory`.

[image]

With your experience in database, please let me know which method is better. In case you need more information about why we divided the data into 2 tables, that is because our notification system can simply identify that it should send notification only for the items in `StudentPass` table, We do not have to do DB comparison to find out which data is the latest and current, we have history and current data separated and it will be easy to generate reports. Your advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing missing from the sample tables above is `BeginDate` and `EndDate` (or whatever you want to call them).  Since you are tracking history, the dates are obviously valuable and can be used when querying older entries.

Having a `StudentPass` and a `StudentPassHistory` table does split out the information, but that is a mixed blessing, since the student's full `StudentPass` information is split across two different tables.

You might consider implementing `StudentPass` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StudentPass
(idStudentPass INT,
 Student_idStudent INT,
 BeginDate Date,
 EndDate Date
 PassActive INT);
```

This way, the `BeginDate` and `EndDate` clearly identify not only whether the `StudentPass` is active, but could also preview for you the approaching `EndDate`.  Likewise, a *future* `BeginDate` could also support setting up a `StudentPass` that will not be activated for a few more weeks.

The `PassActive` is not strictly needed, but can be a useful shortcut for querying active `StudentPass` data without using dates. You just need a process to update the `PassActive` column setting as defined to be in the inclusive range of the `BeginDate` and `EndDate`.

Using a design like this keeps all the information in one table, which I assume will not overwhelm your query processing, so that you can simply filter the data according to your needs.

Of course, if you feel that the `StudentPassHistory` would server you better for some other needs, then make the choice to also create that table.

Comment: Great, will stick with the history table. Thanks!!